# Understanding MaxIdlenessAllowed and TimeRemaining in SYSTEM_POWER_INFORMATION structure

Tags: windows, dll

I am reading power information under Windows 10 using `CallNtPowerInformation` function.
Specifically, I am reading `SystemPowerInformation`.
Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/system-power-information-str

On three different machines, I get:

`MaxIdlenessAllowed` = 0 (always)

`Idleness` = according to the CPU unused %

`TimeRemaining` = 4294967295 (but a few times I read a lower value)

`CoolingMode` = 0

Even if I sleep 20 seconds and read the values after 20 seconds of mouse+keyboard inactivity, I still get `TimeRemaining` = 4294967295.

One of the machines runs an app which resets the idle timer (using SetThreadExecutionState), although there is no difference.

Could you please help me understand what is the logic behind `MaxIdlenessAllowed`  and `TimeRemaining`?

Thanks!